# It says "Trying to load lib" and then application quit without any information

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk

I have download an android program which used tensorflow to realized the emotion recognition. I have finished the work of configuration of environment. And I find that when I use the recognition the application the log says that `"Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.alex.opencvdemo-1/libtensorflow_inference.so 0xa4f77c88"` and then application will quit. I don't know how to solve this problem

Here is my code for loadLibrary

```
static {
        //load libtensorflow_inference.so
      //System.load("/app/com.example.alex.opencvdemo/libs/libtensorflow_interface.so");
        System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
        Log.e("tensorflow","libtensorflow_inference.so is successfully load");
    }
```

And following is my build.gradle of app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alex.opencvdemo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86"}
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets{
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            //jni库的调用会到资源文件夹下libs里面找so文件
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary342')
    implementation files('libs/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` file that is inside the `app` folder?

Comment: I post my build.gradle in the question

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes as i faced this in earlier

1. Better check that your native library matches with 
      "tensorflow_inference".
   Because  in your build.gradle it showsing native_lib something like that.
2. verify tensorflow_inference is added in Cmakelists.txt.
3. if your using openCV make sure you're imported  native libraries fine

Comment: Sorry, I'm almost a newer to Opencv and tensorflow. How can I check these things?

Comment: Are you using openCV libraries in this project? if so   please go through these link https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

Comment: I try to add a new opencv module as this link, but it still doesn't work...